# Database Normalization examples

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am looking forward to learn database normalization with help of some examples.
Putting it simple - How can I make someone learn about Normal forms giving examples.

I looked for some articles online, but did not find them very useful

Comment: What is an example of an article online you looked at that was not helpful?

Comment: It was Microsoft article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Introduction to Database Systems by Chris Date](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321197844)

[Practical Issues in Database Management by Fabian Pascal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485559)

Comment: Can you write an example for SO? I can't find any good examples here and I'm stuck too. Step-by-step 1NF, 2NF, 3NF